# How to choose between spa and mpa in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Hi I am new to angularjs. I have one project in angularjs,web api2,mvc5. I am going to develop ecommerce kind of app where lot of filters,charts,forms,popups etc involved. I have several things in mind. First of all I am concerned about SPA and MPA. How to choose the best one which suits to my requirement?  Can someone help me in this regard. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I would say this goes into the category of too broad and unclear. Your requirements should state what you do. And naturally there are no views in ASP.NET for Web APIs since they're by design not meant to have views. Please clarify what you are trying to do exactly and why you have to use something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to understand the advantages/disadvantages of SPA and MPA.
MPA is traditional approach where each page is fully render with every request and in SPA the require portion of the page is reload. Basically SPA = (MPA + ajax) kind of thing that means SPA based on UI framework rather than server. So performance wise SPA is more reliable than MPA. However you can use hybrid approach also means for any special page (like chart, SVG , graph) you can have another page which is having complex and different type of design and data.